# How to get row values as column values in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

**My output of select statement**

```
ID                Mat      Tes           Para**
15030369.01     Soil    SW-846 6010C    Antimony
15030369.01     Soil    SW-846 6010C    Arsenic
15030369.01     Soil    SW-846 7470A    Mercury
15030369.01     Soil    SW-846 8021B    Benzene
15030369.01     Soil    SW-846 8021B    Ethylbenzene
15030369.01     Soil    SW-846 8021B    Xylenes
15030369.01     Soil    TX 1005         >C12-C28
15030369.01     Soil    TX 1005        >C28-C35
15030369.01     Soil    TX 1005         C6-C12
15030369.01     Soil    TX 1005         C6-5
```

**What i need**

```
ID             Mat           Tes           Par1    Par2          Par3       Par4

15030369.01   Soil      SW-846 6010C    Antimony   Arsenic
15030369.01   Soil      SW-846 7470A    Mercury
15030369.01   Soil      SW-846 8021B    Benzene   Ethylbenzene   Xylenes
15030369.01   Soil      SW-846 6010C    >C12-C28   >C28-C35      C6-C12    C6-5
```

Comment: I believe that you are looking for `PIVOT` sql. Please google it: SQL PIVOT and read about it.

Comment: i Searched for Pivot it makes row value as column header but my requirement is not that... Can u suggest me any other things.. Thank u

Comment: build a sample at [SQL Fiddle](sqlfiddle.com) and put here the link of you sample to make it easy to help you